# Using Mockito to verify is method actually passed successfully and supporting exceptions

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the next method that parses a JSON response.

```
public void parseJSON(JSONObject itemObj) {

  try {
        setId(itemObj.getString("Id"));
        setName(itemObj.getString("Name"));
        JSONObject extraObj = itemObj.getJSONObject("Items");
        ExtraData extra = new ExtraData ();
        extra.parseResponse(extraObj);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
}
```

Now,I want to add some unit testing to it,I don’t know what more you can test here expect the parsing issue, so I prepped a test with the relevant fields and I want to make sure it parsing the relevant fields, and in case it fails to know about it. My problem is that because it’s a mockup , every  `itemObj.getString(“whatever”)` returns `Null` and doesn’t throw exception , so whatever I pass it always succeed.

How can I know that based on the data that I passed it succeeded /failed (throw exception) and not always getting success?

```
@Test
public void parseJSON() throws Exception {
    myClass = Mockito.spy(MyClass.class)
    JSONObject jsonObject = Mockito.mock(org.json.JSONObject.class);
    when(jsonObject.getString(eq("Id"))).thenReturn("555555");
    when(jsonObject.getString(eq("Name"))).thenReturn("John");
    // if removing the “Name” and leaving only “NameIncorrect” it suppose to fails
    //when(jsonObject.getString(eq("NameIncorrect"))).thenReturn("John");

    when(jsonObject.getJSONObject(eq("Items"))).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(JSONObject.class));

    myClass.parseJSON(jsonObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to test your method is to:

1. create a real JSONObject with the data you want to test with.
2. call the method under test with the real JSONObject.
3. check that the calls to `setId()`, `setName()`, etc worked with the data you expected. You might be able to do this by accessing a `myClass.getId()` or similar method?

Comment: about 3 - I want to know that not only these specific calls were called but that the all method completed without exception too.

Comment: If you silently swallow your exception, then you have no real good chance to check for it. So, the solution would be not to silently swallow the exception.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz what do you mean "not to silently swallow the exception" ?

Comment: @RonTf your sample code shows that the exception is being caught, but ignored (empty code block).

Comment: @RonTr, you have omitted at least one bracket, so it's hard to say, but your code example looks like the catch-block is empty, thus, if an exception is thrown, you ignore it, which obviously makes testing the whole thing hard. Also the whole `ExtraData` stuff doesn't seem to change any state in the end, so it will obviously be hard to tell if it was actually called. Testing everything up to the `setName` call is easy, since you can simply check for the name being set - but everything else seems strange and hard to test, which is most often a code smell.

Comment: I actually logging the exception and sending it to server, I didn't add this code because thought it's not important, I'm interested in completed/not completed in my test case

Comment: As I said, your code, especially `extra.parseResponse(extraObj);` does not seem to DO anything that can be somehow noticed, it has no effect, leaves no trace, so it is obviously hard to test. If you can tell us, what the last three lines before the `catch` actually do (except calling a method on a newly created object that doesn't return anything), we can perhaps tell you how you can test that.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = Mockito.mock(org.json.JSONObject.class);
```

...sounds like a good start. If you want to test your exception handling, you could, for example, add...

```
Mockito.when( jsonObject.getJSONObject("Items") ).thenThrow( new JSONException() );
```

This will make the call for your `extraObj` throw a JSONException which will allow you to test your exception handling. Checking for your correct path is a little bit harder, since this...

```
JSONObject extraObj = itemObj.getJSONObject("Items");
ExtraData extra = new ExtraData ();
extra.parseResponse(extraObj);
```

...doesn't seem to actually change any state you can check. In other words, what does this code DO? What happens with the parsed response? Can you check anywhere that it was parsed correctly?

Also...

```
} catch (JSONException e) {
}
```

...seems like you are missing some exception handling here, since you don't handle anything, but ignore it. "If a JSONException occurs, do nothing and continue" is not much of "handling". It CAN be correct, of course.

Comment: The thing is that I want to check that the method called completely without throwing exception, I want to verify that `myClass.parseJSON(jsonObject);` called with success